# Laravel 6: Throttle Password Reset

Tags: throttling, forgot-password, laravel-6.2

In laravel 6 the password broker now has the following to throttle password reset (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L58)

```
public function sendResetLink(array $credentials)
{
    // First we will check to see if we found a user at the given credentials and
    // if we did not we will redirect back to this current URI with a piece of
    // "flash" data in the session to indicate to the developers the errors.
    $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

    if (is_null($user)) {
        return static::INVALID_USER;
    }

    if (method_exists($this->tokens, 'recentlyCreatedToken') &&
        $this->tokens->recentlyCreatedToken($user)) {
        return static::RESET_THROTTLED;
    }

    // Once we have the reset token, we are ready to send the message out to this
    // user with a link to reset their password. We will then redirect back to
    // the current URI having nothing set in the session to indicate errors.
    $user->sendPasswordResetNotification(
        $this->tokens->create($user)
    );

    return static::RESET_LINK_SENT;
}
```

However when I repeatedly submit a password reset why isn't the password reset being throttled - I'm still getting the reset notifications coming through?

I've noticed the `recentlyCreatedToken` method does not exist in TokenRepositoryInterface in version 6.x https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/TokenRepositoryInterface.php

But has been added in version 7.x

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/TokenRepositoryInterface.php

Is this only a feature of v7.x or is there something I need to do that I'm missing?

Answer (score 19):

Password reset throttling works in Laravel 6.x, but for some reason you need to manually set the `throttle` parameter in the config file `config/auth.php`:

```php
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60, // Allows a user to request 1 token per 60 seconds
        ],
    ],
```

[DatabaseTokenRepository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f9b4bc3fbe5d29ea717d3f5b846aa02810fe958f/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php#L68) defines the default value for the throttle time to 60 seconds. But when DatabaseTokenRepository is initialized in [PasswordBrokerManager](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f9b4bc3fbe5d29ea717d3f5b846aa02810fe958f/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php#L93) it checks the config file and if no value was found sets the throttle time to 0 (means disabling the throttle).

Also you need to add the message string to `resources/lang/en/passwords.php` to show the user an understandable error message:

```php
'throttled' => 'You have requested password reset recently, please check your email.',
```

P. S. Don't forget to flush config cache after editing a config file with `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Password reset throttling only works in Laravel 7.x. This feature is unavailable in 6.x see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31513

Comment: @adam78, it's not actually true. It works in Laravel 6.x. Few days ago I implemented password reset throttling in my project with Laravel v6.15.1. And only after that I wrote my answer here. So you can try the above solution and see it by yourself.
Also I attached links to Laravel source code, where it's implemented, but your show me a link to a discussion with suppositions. :-/

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/30373

Comment: Excuse me, what do you want I see there? In the first comment there is a mention of PR #30340 which added password reset throttling to Laravel 6.x - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/30340